# google dataflow running extremely slow slow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, pipeline, apache-beam, dataflow

I have written simple program to read CSV (email) and lookup in datastore for associated id. This also search for AES encryption email.

It was running fine from `directrunner` using eclipse but to get the flow diagram in dataflow i have used `dataflowruuner`. This enables the execution graph but even for 3 records its running sine more than 30 minutes. Why?

using - `DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);`

instead of

```
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(option).withValidation().create();
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on specifics of your pipeline. In general the pipeline startup time will be slower in Dataflow compared to direct runner. E.g. it needs to build and upload the pipeline and then spin up the machines which then need to get the pipeline definition and start executing it. When executing the pipeline in direct runner you usually just compile and run the code locally similar to any other program. So for trivial cases with small data sets that are hard to parallelize the performance benefits of using Dataflow are not obvious.

However, if the pipeline never stops in Dataflow, then you need to see if there are any errors that are preventing it from finishing (e.g. maybe there's some authentication errors, throttling, lack of resources or something else). You can start from looking at Stackdriver: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-stackdriver-monitoring

Some links to documentation, hope it helps:

- [0] Troubleshooting your pipeline - https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/troubleshooting-your-pipeline
- [1] Direct runner - https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/direct/
- [2] Dataflow runner - https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/dataflow/
- [3] Beam + Dataflow slides: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1SlzllDkCtWdg18qKFhxB1EkQAW2ZiG-r80BykODcvVY